# How to use count() across two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get a count across two separate tables. When I run the queries individually the counts are fine. When I try to combine them, the counts are incorrect. Here is the SQL for each separate query.

```
SELECT [Leads Received].[Date Received], Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
     , Count([Leads Received].[Date Received]) AS [CountOfDate Received]
  FROM Employees 
 INNER JOIN [Leads Received] 
    ON Employees.AgentID = [Leads Received].AgentID
 GROUP BY [Leads Received].[Date Received], Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName;


SELECT [Leads Proposed].ACCTGDATE, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
     , Count([Leads Proposed].AgentID) AS CountOfAgentID
  FROM Employees 
 INNER JOIN [Leads Proposed] 
    ON Employees.AgentID = [Leads Proposed].AgentID
 GROUP BY [Leads Proposed].ACCTGDATE, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName;
```

Can anyone help me join these so they display the correct count for each?

Comment: Can you define "combine"? Do you want the counts added together?

Comment: IF you with to "combine" the counts from two tables, you must join the tables or you will receive a cross product of all rows in table a times all rows in table b.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried that produces the incorrect result?  That would give others a better idea of what you mean by "combine".

Comment: Ben - When I say combine, I just want the counts to be on the same query.  What is happening is exactly when DwB stated below your comment.

Comment: SELECT [Leads Received].[Date Received], Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, Count([Leads Received].AgentID) AS CountOfAgentID, Count([Leads Proposed].LEADSTEP) AS CountOfLEADSTEP
FROM (Employees INNER JOIN [Leads Received] ON Employees.AgentID = [Leads Received].AgentID) INNER JOIN [Leads Proposed] ON ([Leads Received].[Date Received] = [Leads Proposed].ACCTGDATE) AND (Employees.AgentID = [Leads Proposed].AgentID)
GROUP BY [Leads Received].[Date Received], Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName;

Comment: Please show an example of the output for 1 AgentID from each select.  I'm trying to understand whether there are multiple [Date Received] and ACCTGDATE values for the same AgentID being returned by each query - and if those dates are different between the two queries.  If that's the case, joining the two queries together to produce the output you want is going to be tricky.